# Plone site doesn't load base.css anymore, and layout is screwed

Tags: css, layout, plone

a few days ago on our site we've enabled ploneFormGen, and after that they layout of the page got screwed, with portlet columns having different widths for headers and items.
I have a backup, whose layout was fine, but content is old, so i'm trying to fix the current site instead.
After doing a lot of comparisons between current site and backup, i realised that while the main template and custom.css are exactly the same, the current site (the screwed one) seems to apply only custom.css according to firebug, while the backup was applying also base.css.

at this stage i'm a bit lost because i have no idea of where i can check why base.css is not applied anymore. Anybody has any clue?
the site is http://www.isf-firenze.org.

thanks!

Comment: It looks like the Plone css files are called after your base css. Try moving your base.css after all the Plone css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.isf-firenze.org/base.css

return an empty file. I think you've a problem with portal_css. Try to switch on/off the development mode, or check if there's an empty base.css in portal_skins/custom.

Comment: thanks @yuri! after enabling development mode on my screwed setup and also on my old setup i've realized that base.css was empty on both sides, and it was actually the public.css stylesheet which wasn't being applied (i had confused it with base.css cause they were being merged in the same cache file). that was due to an empty public.css file in portal_skins/custom. thanks a lot, that was driving me mad! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check `portal_css` (from the ZMI) if base.css is enabled.

Also note that in development mode, all the CSS files are served separately, but in production mode, CSS files are merged and compressed. The URLs for the merged resources are based on the first CSS file included in the bundle, so a URL ending in `custom-cachekey1234.css` could still also include base.css. You can see if resources are merged in the `portal_css` tool (checkbox at the top of the page).

Comment: I've had exactly this happen when installing new products before.  Nobody could come up with a better solution for me than to do as Martijn suggests.

Comment: hi @martijn-pieters and Auspex,thanks for your answers! I've checked my portal.css, and in fact base.css was enabled, and the whole list just looks the same as in my old backup. I've tried enabling development mode, but still base.css was not being applied (i was just seeing a non-cached version of plone custom). I've tried removing it and re-applying it to the list. If i check the "merged css" tab in portal_css in ZMI, i see that base-cache-key-xxx is there, before plone-custom, but in the page it's not rendered... any clue?